# Change custom attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code where I've added custom attributes which I want to change the value of.

```
<div myCustomElement="someValue"></div>
```

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$("#somebutton").click(function() {
    $('myCustomElement').val('SomeNewValue');
});
```

But nothing's being changed. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Why aren't you using data attributes?

Comment: in your case myCustomElement is an attribute not an element

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, inventing your own attributes will mean your HTML is invalid and can lead to issues in your page. Secondly, `val()` is used to directly change the `value` property of the element, hence why it has no effect in your example.

To achieve what you require, use `data-*` attributes, as they are intended for this purpose:

```
<div data-custom="someValue"></div>
```

```js
$("#somebutton").click(function() {
    // getter:
    var foo = $('div').data('custom'); // = 'someValue'

    // setter:
    $('div').data('custom', 'someOtherValue');
});
```

Note that `data()` maintains an object in memory so any amendments you make won't be visible in the DOM.

For more information: http://api.jquery.com/data

Answer (score 1):

Your element isn't custom, it's still a div.

You can do a custom element like so.

```
<myCustomElement></myCustomElement>
```

Then select like

```
$('myCustomElement')...
```

An alternative is to use data-attributes.

```
<div data-myCustomData="test"></div>
```

Then select like so

```
var data = $('div').data('myCustomData')//data = 'test'
```